# How do I change Android Studio 1.3 theme

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to change my theme to Darcula in Android Studio 1.3. I already tried going on File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings (Didn't find IDE Settings on this Android Studio Version) and didn't find anything related with that there. Hope somebody wich is using this version can help me.

There's the only options that appears to me:

[image: File Menu]

[image: Default Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance, then choose your theme in the drop-down list.

[image: Android Studio Appearance Settings Screen]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have not those menu items you said. I just edited my question posting some screenshots from my menu options and Settings window.

Comment: @JoséRodolfoDeFreitasOrtale: You appear to be using OS X. Do you have a Settings or Preferences option in the Apple menu?

Comment: @JoséRodolfoDeFreitasOrtale are you sure you are using 1.3 ?

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah, I'm using OS X and I found that on my Android Studio's menu -> Editor -> Java (I'm programming for Android). Thank's very much anyway.

Comment: @JoséRodolfoDeFreitasOrtale You have found your answer right ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one out:

Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Java > Scheme name

I think you will even find `Appearence` there in the 'Preferences'. The problem is you are searching in the `Default settings`, instead of `Preferences`